# "Prolonged the maintenance frequency" is it correctly phrased?

Tags: grammar, phrase-meaning, phrase-request, phrases, phrase-choice

Let's say the recommended maintenance schedule is once a month or 12 times per year. If the person decided to do xxx, they do not have to maintain it monthly. They can do it less frequently. How can I phrase the sentence to explain that professionally?

Can I say "increase the time interval between maintenance"? or "increase the time interval between scheduled maintenance"?

Also, does "prolonged the maintenance frequency" sound right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both "increase the time interval between maintenance" and "increase the time interval between scheduled maintenance" are fine.

"prolonged the maintenance frequency" is incorrect as frequency is a count over a period of time.

We could instead say "**minimise** the maintenance frequency".